How to Build an AI Chatbot that can do CRUD Operations via API Requests
I'm on a project to develop an AI chatbot capable of performing CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations via API requests. I'm relatively new to this field and would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance you could offer.
My main objectives are to:
Develop an AI chatbot that can understand natural language queries.
Enable the chatbot to interact with an API to perform CRUD operations on a database.
Some specific questions I have include:
What programming languages and frameworks are best suited for this task?
Are there any existing libraries or tools that could streamline the development process?
How should I approach training the chatbot to understand and respond to user queries effectively?
Any insights, tips, or resources you could share would be immensely helpful. Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Well, in my experience always the most viable programming language for this stuff is python. Almost all the community around machine learning and artificial intelligence is around python, so is where you may find more frameworks and the most help from the community.
Regarding the framework, I've been working on a RAG with LangChain and I've really been liking it. It's quite easy to learn and is really well maintained and documented.
Regarding your problem in particular, it seems to be easily solved via function calling. It's basically extracting the parameters of a function from a natural language query. You don't need to train anything (tho it will improve your results) just do a little of prompt engineering.
